# Can I add והבאת שלום בין משפחה למשפחה to אלו דברים in the morning?

Tags: shabbat, marriage, family-members, shalom-peace, leket-shichecha-peah

Rashi says about the altar that we can't wave a sword over it in משפטים, the maftir. 
Can I add his opinion (above included also) to the list of אלו דברים שאדם אוכל פירותיהם בעולם הזה in Shacharit? What halachot might prevent me from adding to the tefillah? This particular mishnah appears to have several sources, and the version in many siddurim does not match תלמוד בבלי מסכת שבת, קכז עמוד א -ב  or משנה מסכת פאה, פרק א, משנה א but I know is discussed [here](http://midreshet.org.il/pageview.aspx?id=1469).

Comment: Note this isn't part of Tefillah. Birkot HaTorah are Berakhot said before performing a Mitzva. Any Torah study can be said after them. (I don't know why you'd think to change the text of a Mishna; that just seems dishonest.)

Comment: @double-aa It would seem it's not exactly a Mishna, it's an agreed-upon formulation used by the siddur.

Comment: It is a berayita I think, the text is a way to link the Birkat Hatora to Mikra, Mishna and Beraita. Mikra Yevarechecha... Mishna Elu devarim sheein... Berayita Elu devarim Sheadam ochel... quasi sure. anyway, the nusach in sepharadic siddurim contains also Ben Ish LeIshto. ... but to change is contrary to the rules of Shinun Tora Shebeal pe. So it is not good.

Comment: Rashi includes it in an identical list, though on his commentary to waving in Yitro (not Mishpatim, my mistake) כב in a kal v'chomer near the end on the subject of waving a sword over the stone mizbeah nested in between the two last items of nusach ashkenaz's version of this - which is included in the Torah b'al pe - what if the Berayita was damaged?

Comment: @kouty *There's no way the Berayita was damaged, the sages obviously knew that what Rashi knew. Why was it left out of the Nusach Ashkenaz?

Comment: Why wouldn't this be allowed? It doesn't "change the brocho into a long/short brocho." (Brachos 2)

Comment: This wording is from the *Sifra* (*K'doshim* 4:11): "אדם שמטיל שלום בין איש לאשתו **בין משפחה למשפחה** בין עיר לעיר ובין מדינה למדינה ובין אומה לחברתה עאכ"ו שלא תבואהו הפורענות". The wording in the siddur is mostly based on the gemara in *Shabbos* 127a about things that "אדם אוכל פירותיהן בעולם הזה והקרן קיימת לו לעולם הבא" (and other sources about what's considered in the category of "גמילות חסדים"), whereas the statement from the *Sifra* is a separate statement that a person will not suffer from making peace between different families.

Comment: @Fred I think that you can enlighten the question of to think to a good positive answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to know about appending a clause into this paragraph because you'd like to include a prayer for family unity.

The minhag is to say this "memra" after Birkas Kohanim so we may follow the b'racha with mikra, mishna, and memra. (Mishna B'rura 47,21). In fact, the statement as it appears in the siddur is a conglomeration of several nusachaos by Amoraim, etc., as you alluded to. In any case, the version canonized in the siddur is a list of mitzvos with a unique quality; namely, they grant a benefit to the doer in this world, beyond the reward they earn the doer in the world to come.

With this understanding in mind, adding to this list would be out of place, 1) because whatever more I add does not in fact share the quality of the other elements in the list; the list already includes all those mitzvos that share this quality, and 2) the list is not one of requests.

Comment: See the comment of @Fred from the Sifra

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean to show. That comment merely shows that the phrase appears in a Sifra. I was addressing the question of inserting extraneous phrases into the memra of Chazal. My point was that extraneous insertions don't have a place, which is what I understood the questioner to be asking.

Comment: `the list already includes all those mitzvos that share this quality` Are you sure? A few of the items added into the siddur's list are subcategories of "*g'milus chasadim*." Aren't there other subcategories of *g'milus chasadim* that aren't listed explicitly in the siddur?

Comment: @Fred   I think it's sensible to say that the memra cited is providing an exhaustive list. If more elements would belong in the list, the memra would be misleading in omitting them.
As far as the apparent redundancy: While there are many things that are included in g'milus chasadim, those that are singled out take primacy. For example - If I have the choice to perform בקור חולים or give someone a ride, בקור חולים would take precedence. I heard this explanation once from R' Feivel Cohen, שליט"א, and it was based on a רמב"ם. I apologize for not remembering the רמב"ם.

Comment: @Talmid Just wondering: Do you know the original source for the exact version we have in our siddurim? Because by your logic we may as well add in the other extra items mentioned by R' Yochanan in [*Shabbos* 127a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=127&format=text) ("והמגדל בניו לתלמוד תורה והדן את חברו לכף זכות"), as those would also be prime examples of the "*talmud Torah*" category and the "*hava'as shalom bein adam lachaveiro*" category, respectively (cf. Rashi *Shabbos* 127b s.v. "הני נמי בהני שייכי").

Comment: @Fred  Not only do I _not_ know the earliest source for that particular formulation, but the Rambam in his his סדר התפלה - designed for the siddur - had it differently (end of sefer Ahava).

Comment: @Talmid Very well. Even the *Mishna B'rura* you cited doesn't specify which version to say (I'd guess he'd advocate using R' Yochanan's actual statement). Especially since it's not even a prayer (as you point out in your answer), I wouldn't say that the siddur's version has been "canonized" as part of the *seder hat'filla*. The issue I'm concerned about is not altering *ma'amarei Chazal* by interpolating the phrase from the *Sifra* where it doesn't necessarily belong. I see no problem whatsoever with using the gemara's version, and it may even be preferable to the siddur's version.

Comment: @Fred Fundamentally, I hear you very well. The reason I would hesitate in practice is based on a sensitivity that I saw by my Rabbeim, and what they have told me from their Rabbeim, regarding accepted nuschaos (as an example). If a certain nusach was widespread for a long time, they would be very apprehensive in calling it into question. I would be interested to know in which lands and for how long our present nusach has been extant. Are we looking at a young sapling or a firmly rooted cedar? If the latter, there's likely good cause, and should be left. That's my impression from my Rabbeim.

Comment: @Talmid `I would be interested to know in which lands and for how long our present nusach has been extant. Are we looking at a young sapling or a firmly rooted cedar?` That's a good question. You can [ask it here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/ask), if you like. :)